# How to sum up Run time hours based on Work Center using SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to sum up Run Time hours based on Work Centre. For example, if Work Center is 108, then sum up Run Time hours for these work centers : 572, 257, 107, 102 and 108. But if work center 108 is not present, then do not sum up.

Here is example with work center 108:

```
Work Center     Run Time Hours
572            0.025
257            1
107            4.284
102           19.046
108            4.865
```

So the total Rum time hours should come : 29.22

But if Work Center 108 is not present, I do not want to Sum up the total Run Time hours even other work centers  572, 257 107 and 102 are present.

```
Work Center     Run Time Hours
572               0.025
257               1
107               4.284
102              19.046
```

I tired:

```
SUM(
  CASE 
    WHEN routingoperations.workcentreid IN ('108', '107','102','105','255','257','572')
        THEN (dbo.routingoperations.runtime) 
  END) AS [Total Runtime Hours]
```

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just using a GROUP BY clause? If Work Centre 108 is not in your dataset it will not appear in the aggreagation.
If you want to filter out some records, put them in the WHERE clause.

Just like this:

```
    SELECT
        WorkCenter
        ,TotalRunTime = SUM([Run Time Hours])
    FROM [table]
    GROUP BY
        WorkCenter
WHERE
Workcenter NOT IN ('1','2','3','4')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I tried but not luck. Here is my sample SQL

Comment: SELECT dbo.worksorders.partid, dbo.worksorders.id 
,SUM(CASE WHEN routingoperations.workcentreid IN ('108', '107','102','105','255','257','572') THEN (dbo.routingoperations.runtime) END) AS [SMT Routing Time]
FROM   dbo.worksorders INNER JOIN
dbo.allpartmaster ON dbo.allpartmaster.partnum = dbo.worksorders.partid INNER JOIN
dbo.routingoperations ON dbo.allpartmaster.partnum = dbo.routingoperations.partid LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.WORKORDERS_LEADTIME ON dbo.worksorders.id = dbo.WORKORDERS_LEADTIME.WorkOrders
GROUP BY dbo.worksorders.partid, dbo.worksorders.id

Comment: Also I forget to mention that there are other work centers .. i.e. 728, 901, 850, 960 etc. So I can't just sum up the whole column as you suggest "Sum([Run Time Hours]). I need to filter out other work centers. Hope I explained well.

Comment: Just add a WHERE clause to your SELECT statement. Do a simple SUM(runtime) add to the end:  WHERE routingoperations.workcentreid IN ('108', '107','102','105','255','257','572')

Comment: By putting your WHERE Workcenter NOT IN ('728','901','850','960'), it gives me total sum hours. But I want : If Work Center = 108, then ONLY sum up for these workcenter: 572,257,107,102 and 108. If Work Center 108 is not present, then do not sum up any hours. Sorry if I am not explaining well, but it looks like challenge to me. Again thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment: 
If this is a static case then you need to check first that is there any record where Work centre = 108 and then do a sum. You can do this with an IF EXISTS statement.
Like this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM WorkCenter WHERE WorkCenter = '108')
BEGIN
    SELECT      
        TotalRunTime = SUM(RunTimeHours)
    FROM WorkCenter
    WHERE
        WorkCenter in ('572','257','107','102','108')   
END
ELSE
    SELECT TotalRunTime = 0
```

If you have various different cases based on workcenters then this logic is not the best solution.